# Pipeline PDF conversion original document URI

Tags: marklogic

CPF converts PDF for me to XHTML. That works fine, when it's in XHTML, I have another pipeline enriching the data. This also works fine.

I notice that I do not get the original document URI from the PDF conversion pipeline, only the URI for the XHTML file.

What I can do is convert the XHTML URI using a construction of replaces, but I rather keep the original URI during all pipelines:

```
/converted/Berry, Steve - Het Venetiaans bedrog_pdf.xhtml

into

/pdf/Berry, Steve - Het Venetiaans bedrog.pdf
```

I've taken a look at `/MarkLogic/conversion/actions/convert-pdf-action.xqy` but it does not become clear to me me where I should add some code.

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already using CPF, then you already have property fragments. I would suggest that you keep any information like this that you may want as a property. Likewise, you could also add a collection on the first step and copy it to each newly created document form the previous step.

Either of these approaches can end up with the original URI as a type of collation ID

Comment: thanks, I never realized these property documents are created by the CPF, the source document (origin URI) is already in there :)

Comment: And CPF's use of property fragments is why I do not use it in some cases. 3-4 steps in the pipeline probably ends up in close to a dozen commits because state changes as part of CPF all change properties (which is transactional).

It is a good tool, but needs to be handled with care. Other uses of CPF is to use to to add documents to a collection and treat this like a queue  - then use cORB[2] to do the heavy work for example.